# Remove an email address from apple-ID

Tags: email, apple-id

I have two Apple IDs:

- One (lets say `A`) associated with my old email address (lets say `old@xyz`), which is the one I actually use
- Another one (lets say `B`) associated with my new email address (lets say `new@xyz`), which I created when I was in the US.

Now I want to associate `new@xyz` to the account `A`. However I'm not able because that mail is already used for the account `B`.
I tried to change the primary email of the account `B` with `another_one@xyz`, but then, when I try to change the primary mail of the account `A` with `new@xyz` it says that the mail address is already verified with another account (the B).

Is there a way for dissociating an email from an apple ID?
In other words, how can I use `new@xyz` with the account `A` when the address is alraedy used for the account `B`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t remove the primary email address associated with the account. You can set another one as the primary, but the first email address that you use to create the account with cannot be changed ever. Not even by calling Apple. I tried. Eventually, I created a dummy gmail account to get my invoices and stuff. Once an email address is verified, there is no way to “unverify” it.

Comment: It is wrong. I found a solution: https://df.tips/t/1871/4

Comment: Would you like to answer this or [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/467946/5472) properly? I can unblock the protection here if you would like. @DmitriiFediuk